# How can I bind correctly my variables to my tokens?

Tags: pdo, kendo-ui

I can't figure out what causes this error, I'm burned out already. I can't figure out how to solve this.

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter
>   number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\wamp64\www\myproject-dev\public\viajes\orden_mantenimiento\controller.php on line *77*

This happens when I try to execute my create method so heres the whole method:

```
if ($type == 'create') {
        $Records = $request->models;
        foreach ($Records as $rec) {
            if (isset($request->pky)) {
                $fky = $request->fky;
                $rec->$fky = $request->pky;
            }

            $aError = Validate($rec);

            $statement = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO order (id, idVehiculo, idTipo, fecha, kilometraje, horaIn, horaSal, proyecto, jefeProy, aprobadoPor, descripcion) 
                                            VALUES (:id, :idVehiculo, idTipo, :fecha, :kilometraje, :horaIn, :horaSal, :proyecto, :jefeProy, :aprobadoPor, descripcion)');

                $statement->bindValue(':id', $rec->id);
                $statement->bindValue(':idVehiculo', $rec->idVehiculo);
                $statement->bindValue(':idTipo', $rec->idTipo);
                $statement->bindValue(':fecha', $rec->fecha);
                $statement->bindValue(':kilometraje', $rec->kilometraje);
                $statement->bindvalue(':horaIn', $rec->horaIn);
                $statement->bindvalue(':horaSal', $rec->horaSal);
                $statement->bindValue(':proyecto', $rec->proyecto);
                $statement->bindValue(':jefeProy', $rec->jefeProy);
                $statement->bindValue(':aprobadoPor', $rec->aprobadoPor);
                $statement->bindValue(':descripcion', $rec->descripcion);

                if (!$statement->execute()) {  // **========================== THIS IS LINE 77 ===================**
                    $aErrInfo = $statement->errorInfo();
                    $aError = array();
                    $aError[] = array('success' => false);
                    $aError[] = array('msg' => $aErrInfo[1]);
                    $aError[] = array('error' => $aErrInfo[2]);
                    $respuesta["errors"] = $aError;
                    echo "statement error".$respuesta;
                } else {
                    $rec->id = $conn->lastInsertId();
                    $respuesta["data"] = $rec;
                    echo "Data bound.";
                }
            } else {
                $respuesta["errors"] = $aError;
                echo "ERROR";
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You are missing a colon `:` in front of `descripcion` in your values statement.

Comment: Change `VALUES (:id, :idVehiculo, idTipo, :fecha, :kilometraje, :horaIn, :horaSal, :proyecto, :jefeProy, :aprobadoPor, descripcion)');` to `VALUES (:id, :idVehiculo, idTipo, :fecha, :kilometraje, :horaIn, :horaSal, :proyecto, :jefeProy, :aprobadoPor, :descripcion)');`

Comment: Thanks A LOT, I didn't notice it.